# Am I understanding this spec on getter functions correctly?

Tags: javascript

In MDN doc on [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) I see:

> It must not appear in an object literal with another get or with a
> data entry for the same property (`{ get x() { }, get x() { } }` and `{ x: ..., get x() { } }` are forbidden).

I interpreted this to mean there can't be more than 1 getter method in an object but this doesn't seem to be a problem.

```js
o1 = {

get fun1() {console.log(5)},
get fun2() {console.log(6)},

};

o1.fun1;
o1.fun2;
```

Was my understanding right?

Comment: What MDN means is that: 1. You can't have a regular property and a getter with the same name. 2. You can't have 2 getters with the same name. You can have more than one getters in an object literal provided that you don't break the previously mentioned rules.

Comment: ...but it doesn't say anything about getters with **different** names

Comment: Key phrase is **"for the same property"**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the MDN article is saying is that you cannot have a getter method and a regular property with the same name on an object, e.g.:

```js
const obj = {
    x: 1,
    //Getter overwrites the data property, as it appears later
    get x() {console.log('Getter invoked')}
}

console.log(obj.x); //undefined, data property was overwritten
```

is forbidden. Having two getters on different methods is absolutely fine.